# clip sf polygon using another sf polygon

Tags: r, raster, shapefile, r-sf

If I have to crop a raster for a irregular shapefile (for e.g. a country), I would do a `crop` followed by `mask` as follows:

```
library(raster)
r <- crop(my_raster, extent(polygon))
r <- mask(r, polygon)
```

Is there any equivalent of doing the same for polygons. I tried the below to clip world river basin shapefile for a given country but it only returned me the basins that were included in the extent and not the basin following the boundary of the shapefile

```
  library(sf)
  cropped <- st_crop(river_basins, country_shapefile)
```

Comment: consider using `sf::st_intersection()` - in addition you might find the sf cheatsheet (https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/main/sf.pdf) handy...

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377964/clip-function-in-the-sf-package-in-r

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317804/is-there-a-way-to-clip-a-layer-with-a-shape-from-another-layer-in-sf

Comment: Including the link from the answer below, since as is, it's a link only answer which would get deleted: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/07/clipping-spatial-data-in-r/#google_vignette